# Images in Page attachments vs Media library Kentico

Tags: azure-blob-storage, attachment, kentico, azure-cdn, media-library

When we are hosting kentico application in cloud let's say Azure, We configure blob storage and the media library files lets say images reside in Azure blob. 
Now while fetching those files we also configure Azure CDN and the some caching techniques and the page load time is saved.

Now while working with page attachments, In Kentico there is a possibility of storing those page attachments either in DB or file system.

Also configuring azure blob storage kentico says in regards to Map the whole file system to Azure storage

We do not recommend mapping the whole file system to the Azure storage because of possible problems with local smart search indexes and Web analytics functionality. These features use data that is not suitable for shared file systems.
Here is the [link](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/working-with-physical-files-using-the-api/configuring-file-system-providers/configuring-azure-storage)

1. Now if we are storing the images in page attachments (custom page types), then is there any way that we can save those page attachment images in azure blob and utilize azure cdn so that images that are rendering as page attachments will also get reduce load time.
2. Basically what are the ways the images stored as page attachments can reduce the page load time.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the default out-of-the-box Kentico configuration allows configuring Azure or Amazon CDN only for media library files. We typically customize it like this:

1. Point your domain to CDN and CDN point to Kentico server (or web app):

   - mysite.com -> CDN -> Kentico server
   - depending on caching headers returned by your Kentico site CDN will cache the response or not
   - you can configure caching time in response headers for media files and attachments as explained in [the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k12sp/configuring-kentico/configuring-caching/caching-files-and-resources)
   - you need to make sure for HTML you set correct cache headers to either cache it on CDN or not
2. Create a subdomain for your media files like media.mysite.com

   - HTML will be served directly from your server: browser -> Kentico server
   - media files and attachments will be served from CDN: browser -> CDN -> Kentico website
   - you need to point this media sub-domain to CDN: media.mysite.com -> CDN -> Kentico server
   - when you render media file links or attachments in your HTML you need to generate a link like this yourself: instead of relative URLs like "/getmedia/..." or "/getattachment/..." you need absolute URLs like "https://media.mysite.com/getmedia/..." or "https://media.mysite.com/getattachment/..."